# JavaScript. Sorting ements by value of children

Tags: javascript, sorting

Need a bit of help with JS. I'm trying to figure out how to sort a pile of div's, using values of their children elements. I'v found a solution here on stack and tried to modify it a bit but with no luck so far.
Please, give me some advise. Thank you

The idea is to sort div.person according to their "age" element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sort list items alphabetically with Javascript</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function sortUnorderedList(div, sortDescending) {
          if(typeof div == "number")
            div = document.getElementById(div);

          var lis = div.getElementsByClassName("person");
          var vals = [];

          for(var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
            vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);

          vals.sort();

          if(sortDescending)
            vals.reverse();

          for(var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
            lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];
        }

        window.onload = function() {
          var desc = false;
          document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() {
            sortUnorderedList("list", desc);
            desc = !desc;
            return false;
          }
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="test" value="Sort List"/>
        <div id="list">
            <div class="person">
              <div>Jack</div>
              <div>Plumber</div>
              <div class="info">
                  <span class="age">24</span>
                  <span class="hair-color">Blonde</span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="person">
              <div>Jill</div>
              <div>Actress</div>
              <div class="info">
                  <span class="age">18</span>
                  <span class="hair-color">Gray</span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="person">
              <div>John</div>
              <div>Driver</div>
              <div class="info">
                  <span class="age">37</span>
                  <span class="hair-color">Brown</span>
              </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Surely you meant `if(typeof div == "string")`

Comment: Which solution did you find? Please link it - and show us your attempt at modifying it!

Comment: This was an original solution - http://jsfiddle.net/stodolaj/De8Ku/. The one I've showed here is my attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code a bit to make it more readable for myself.

First I get all the htmlNode by class name "person", though this will return a htmlCollection which is array-ish but not an array.
Therefore I convert it to an array on the next line so I can perform array-methods on it like 'sort'.
You can swap out the different compareFunctions I wrote for different kind of sorting.
After sorting I empty the existing content of the list-element, and fill it up again with for-loop.

```js
function sortUnorderedList(list, sortDescending) {
  var htmlCollection = list.getElementsByClassName("person"),
    elements = [].slice.call(htmlCollection); //convert htmlCollection to array

  //sort by ...
  //elements.sort(compareNames);
  //elements.sort(compareJobs);
  elements.sort(compareAges);

  if (sortDescending) elements.reverse();

  list.innerHtml = ''; //remove current contents

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    list.appendChild(elements[i]); //add them again in different order
  }

  function compareNames(el1, el2) {
    //innerText of the first child of each element is the name
    if (el1.children[0].innerText < el2.children[0].innerText) return -1;
    if (el1.children[0].innerText > el2.children[0].innerText) return 1;
    return 0;
  }

  function compareJobs(el1, el2) {
    //innerText of the second child of each element is the job
    if (el1.children[1].innerText < el2.children[1].innerText) return -1;
    if (el1.children[1].innerText > el2.children[1].innerText) return 1;
    return 0;
  }

  function compareAges(el1, el2) {
    var age1 = parseInt(el1.children[2].children[0].innerText),
      age2 = parseInt(el2.children[2].children[0].innerText);
    if(isNaN(age1))age1=-1;
    if(isNaN(age2))age2=-1;
    return age1 - age2;
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  var desc = false;
  document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() {
    sortUnorderedList(document.getElementById('list'), desc);
    desc = !desc;
    return false;
  };
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sort list items alphabetically with Javascript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" id="test" value="Sort List" />
  <div id="list">
    <div class="person">
      <div>Jack</div>
      <div>Plumber</div>
      <div class="info">
        <span class="age">24</span>
        <span class="hair-color">Blonde</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="person">
      <div>Jill</div>
      <div>Actress</div>
      <div class="info">
        <span class="age">0</span>
        <span class="hair-color">Gray</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="person">
      <div>John</div>
      <div>Driver</div>
      <div class="info">
        <span class="age"></span>
        <span class="hair-color">Brown</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. But how can I adjust it a bit more when, for example, I have no value inside "age" element? Right now it will be treated like "0", but I want that empty element always be at the bottom of the list and not taking part in sorting process.

Comment: If you have no value in the age element it's going to be treated as NaN.
I tried fiddling around with it, but I never get the desired result. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: @bewell, I found out how to do it, check for isNaN, and if it's not a number set the age to -1.